# Restricting RW access to NFS shares

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs

I have the a Qumulo storage system which just creates an NFS mount that our Linux clients can mount and access.  In our Environment we have our Linux servers configured to authenticate with AD via RFC2307

We have this mounted on the server fine and we've found that this will allow the user to write to this folder whether or not they are in the proper groups.  So essentially everyone that can login to the Linux server read and write files in this directory.

```
[root@LinuxServer proj]# showmount -e org-fs
Export list for org-fs:
/         (everyone)
/Home     (everyone)
/Projects (everyone)
/NBU      (everyone)



[root@LinuxServer proj]# ls -lah /mnt/proj
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root         4.0K May 11 14:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root         4.0K May 11 14:19 ..
drwxrwx--- 3 root smith_lab  512 May 10 15:36 Smith



[root@LinuxServer Smith]# ls -lah /mnt/proj/Smith
total 12K
drwxrwx--- 3 root smith_lab  512 May 10 15:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root         4.0K May 11 14:19 ..
drwxrwx--- 2 root smith_lab  512 May 21 11:55 Smith


[root@LinuxServer Smith]# mount
org-fs:/Projects/Smith on /mnt/proj/Smith type nfs (rw,addr=192.168.2.33)



[root@LinuxServer project1]# ls -lah /mnt/proj/Smith/project1/
total 12K
drwxrwx--- 2 root     smith_lab  512 May 21 12:26 .
drwxrwx--- 3 root     smith_lab  512 May 10 15:36 ..
-rwxrwx--- 1 phonic org_default  10 May 21 12:26 Test.txt



[root@LinuxServer project1]# id phonic
uid=10952(phonic) gid=10000(org_default) groups=10000(org_default),10021(webadmin),10005(it_admin)
```

As you can see phonic's main group is org_default.  This group does not have access to smith_lab in AD nor am I a member of any smith_lab group.  However it let me create a Test.txt file in that directory.  Most of my google searches are coming back as "I want to give RW access to everyone"  I already have that, I'm trying to take it away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow I can't believe I didn't figure this out.  Propagation through the domain appeared to be slow.  I'd add myself to the group and I can write, I removed myself and I could still write.  I logged out of the system and waited ~1hr and when I came back to it I could no longer write to it.  I waited previously about 15 minutes and I could still write to it.  I guess it needed the full time.